# what does {} and format do in this command python?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, coverage.py

Hi i am reading a source and it has a line:

```
fn = 'total-listmix-{}-{}.xml'.format(opt.os, opt.compiler)
exept Exception as e:
    raise Exception('error merging coverage: {}'.format(e))
```

I think the `{}` mean a `dict` but i do not understand what `dict` here ? Is is a `dict` took from `format` ?

Comment: It's not a dict. `{}` is inside the string. It's a placeholder for the values being printed. The documentation for `format`, which you can find online, explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{}` is a replacement field, not a `dict`. This is mentioned in the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

One simple example is:

```
name = "Tom"
print("Hello, {}".format(name)) # prints "Hello, Tom"
```

Here are a few more examples from the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
"First, thou shalt count to {0}"  # References first positional argument
"Bring me a {}"                   # Implicitly references the first positional argument
"From {} to {}"                   # Same as "From {0} to {1}"
"My quest is {name}"              # References keyword argument 'name'
"Weight in tons {0.weight}"       # 'weight' attribute of first positional arg
"Units destroyed: {players[0]}"   # First element of keyword argument 'players'.
```

And this is the grammar of the replacement field:

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | digit+]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

Comment: Can i understand that we will take the value from `format(e)` to put in the string: `error merging coverage: {}` ?